# How to link a Circular Linked List to a Doubly Linked List?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list called **MMD**,
it contains following information of each track:

- **MBID (4-digit unique number)**
- **Song Name**
- **Writer**
- **Length**

  ```
   template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> 
   class MMD 
   { 
  public:
    //data members
    T1 mbid;
    //AD* album = nullptr;
    T2 songName;
    T2 writer;
    T3 length;

    //connections
    MMD* next;
    MMD* previous;
    MMD* head;
    MMD* tail;

    MMD( )
    {
        next = nullptr;
        previous = nullptr;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        mbid = 0;
        songName = "\0";
        writer = "\0";
        length = 0.0;
    }
  };
  ```

I have another circular singly linked list called **AD** and it contains:

- **ABID (4-digit unique number)**
- **Album Name**
- **Publisher**
- **Number of Tracks**
- **Total Duration**
- **and a Tracks (singly linked list) with data members**

  - *Track Number*
  - *MBID (4-digit unique number)* // for connecting the song

`template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>`

```
 class AD
 {
 public:
 //data members
 T1 abid;
 T2 albumName;
 T2 publisher;
 T1 noOfTracks;
 T3 duration;
 Tracks<T1,T2,T3>* tracks;
//connections
AD* next;
AD* head = NULL;

AD()
{
    abid = 0;
    albumName = " ";
    publisher = " ";
    noOfTracks = 0;
    duration = 0.0;
}
};
```

AD database will be connected to the MMD database. The MMD will be connected via the MBID.
Node in MMD having same MBID must have a two-way relationship i.e. If pointer
is at some Node in AD and wants to access music metadata about that track, it should be able to
directly access that Node in MMD without the need of searching the whole Music Metadata
Database to locate and see Music record against concerned MBID and vice-versa.

I am totally clueless about doing this, can someone please suggest an algorithm for this problem.

Comment: Unrelated, why do you need template?

Comment: Recommendation: Separate the logic of the track listing from the logic of the linked lists. You may find you can reuse a lot of the code, and you may also find it's a lot easier to debug two classes  that each represent one concern than one class that represents 2 concerns.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep, using templates is requirement to pass test cases.